# Can I get a calibrated image and skeleton from the Official Kinect SDK at the same time?

Tags: sdk, colors, kinect, depth

Basically, I just want those three things.

Color, Depth, and Skeleton. But I also want the depth and color lined up.

I know that in the official examples, there's GreenScreen.cpp, which is an example of depth/color cut-outs, but no skeleton. There's also SkeletonBasics which has a skeleton, but no image.

I've tried learning from both of them and implementing them together, but I never get a callback for when the skeleton is ready (this: m_hNextSkeletonEvent).

**SkeletonBasics.cpp uses this:**

```
    hEvents[0] = m_hNextSkeletonEvent;

    // Check to see if we have either a message (by passing in QS_ALLEVENTS)
    // Or a Kinect event (hEvents)
    // Update() will check for Kinect events individually, in case more than one are signalled
    DWORD dwEvent = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(eventCount, hEvents, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);

    // Check if this is an event we're waiting on and not a timeout or message
    if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == dwEvent)
    {
        Update();
    }
```

**And GreenScreen.cpp uses this:**

```
    hEvents[0] = m_hNextDepthFrameEvent;
    hEvents[1] = m_hNextColorFrameEvent;

    // Check to see if we have either a message (by passing in QS_ALLINPUT)
    // Or a Kinect event (hEvents)
    // Update() will check for Kinect events individually, in case more than one are signalled
    DWORD dwEvent = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(eventCount, hEvents, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);

    // Check if this is an event we're waiting on and not a timeout or message
    if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == dwEvent || WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1 == dwEvent)
    {
        Update();
    }
```

But, like I said, combining them yields no

if ( WAIT_OBJECT_0 == WaitForSingleObject(m_hNextSkeletonEvent, 0) )

happening. (The KinectBridgeWithOpenCVBasics-D2D also does Skeleton, Color, and Depth, but still is unaligned [(like this example I found in a search)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/64206).

Do you know why the event is not firing? Or perhaps do you know of an example somewhere that has all of these abilities? I've searched high and low, and I've tried tons of different things messing with these examples, but I just cant seem to get it.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
At the end of KinectBridgeWithOpenCVBasics, I'm left with a m_colorMat and an m_depthMat. Even if at that point I could align the depth to color, I think that would work out just fine.

Comment: I've only delt with managed code, so I am speaking to that experience... I do not see where you subscribe to the particular events; I see the handlers, but not where you set them up.  Short answer - it is all possible (in C# and C++), so something is just a bit off.  I just can't pick it out as easily in C++.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As far as I could tell, I initialized everything correctly. I copied all the HANDLE starts into the .h file, and set each "CreateEventW" up the same way. I also made sure it had all the flags in NuiInitialize. I just don't know where else to go with it.